# How to efficiently get all valid values of an attribute from an NSManagedObject?

Tags: iphone, core-data, ios

I have an iPhone app with a Core Data object that has a "color" attribute.  I'd like to get a list of all the values for color that have been saved.  A simple SQL statement `SELECT DISTINCT(color) FROM myObjectTable` would easily do this.  How can I do this in Core Data without loading all the objects (of which there may be thousands) into an in-memory NSSet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

1) set NSFetchRequest's requestType to NSDictionaryResultType

2) "setPropertiesToFetch" in NSFetchRequest to fetch only the property instead of the whole object.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a good solution to this yet either. But you can as Nevin suggests get specific attributes instead of the entire managed objects.

See [Fetching Specific Values](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html) from Apple's documentation for more detail.

You will get a NSArray of NSDictionary objects that you can then loop through, extracting the color values that you are looking for.